# Sane way to use boost::program_options with INI and command line?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I want to write a program that parses a config file, and allows the command line to override what's written there. So I can have a config file that says:

```
[section1]
opt1=42

[section2]
opt2=17
```

And then, I can run the command with:

```
./so --opt2=3
```

And the program will get `opt1` as 42 and `opt2` and 3. I use the following program to try and do it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    po::options_description options1("section1");
    options1.add_options()
            ("opt1", po::value<int>(), "Option 1");

    po::options_description options2("section2");
    options2.add_options()
            ("opt2", po::value<int>(), "Option 2");

    po::options_description options;
    options.add(options1);
    options.add(options2);

    po::variables_map values;
    po::store( po::command_line_parser( argc, argv ).options(options).run(), values );

    std::ifstream iniFile( "options.ini" );

    po::store(
            parse_config_file( iniFile, options ),
            values );
}
```

This, of course, doesn't work. Boost::program_options wants `opt1` under `section1` to be called `section1.opt1`. If I do that, however, my program becomes harder to maintain on two fronts:

- I need to define two `options_description`s, one for the INI and one for the command line.
- Since the options' keys are now different, I need to manually merge the two.

Is there a way achieve this without doing the work manually?

Answer (score -1):

The trivial solution is, to not use the sections. There might be some confusion around "sections" in the options descriptions vs. sections in ini-files.

The sections in ini-files refer *only* to options named with embedded periods: `"section1.opt1"`. So you can simply write the config file as:

```
opt1=42

# perhaps with a comment
opt2=17
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ed7d56aa4b3319f)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    po::options_description options;
    options.add_options()
        ("opt1", po::value<int>(), "Option 1")
        ("section2.opt2", po::value<int>(), "Option 2");

    std::cout << options << "\n";

    po::variables_map values;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, options), values);

    std::ifstream iniFile("options.ini");

    po::store(parse_config_file(iniFile, options), values);

    auto report = [&values](char const* name) {
        if (auto opt = values[name]; !opt.empty())
            std::cout << name << ": " << opt.as<int>() << "\n";
    };

    report("opt1");
    report("opt2");
    report("section1.opt1");
    report("section2.opt2");
}
```

Prints

```
echo "opt1=42" >> options.ini; ./a.out --section2.opt2 99
  --opt1 arg            Option 1
  --section2.opt2 arg   Option 2

opt1: 42
section2.opt2: 99
```

Comment: If you still requirethe sections, you **can** do some post-processing like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780447/how-to-store-data-in-boostprogram-optionsvariable-map/63785686#63785686) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62399047/boost-program-options-store-multiple-config-file-parse-results-into-one-parsed-o/62433436#62433436) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62396785/85371)

Comment: The answer completely ignores the question. An answer saying "you can't do that" would have been marginally helpful. You answer essentially says "the solution to getting sections is not to use sections". Your answer is _literally_ a repeat of the information in the question.

Comment: Okay. That's a harsh read, but I appreciate the explanation.

Comment: I parsed the question more as "this doesn't do what I expect/hoped", which is
why I zoomed in on the possible source of confusion (description sections
aren't "sections").

Since your question only centers on changing /one side/ (the descriptions), I
elected to go the other way (changing the config file), which does meet all the
stated requirements. I acknowledged that changing might not be your intent in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002249/sane-way-to-use-boostprogram-options-with-ini-and-command-line/64037252?noredirect=1#comment113239277_64037252).

Comment: I guess the upshot is that the answer is, by your own evaluation, "marginally helpful". I submit that by [SO] etiquette that doesn't normally warrant a downvote. Sorry for any confusion I caused in the wording of my answer (communication is hard). Cheers.